# Vagrant plugin command is not available when running `vagrant plugin install`

Tags: vagrant, berkshelf

I have tried installing vagrant from both an apt repo and gem but here's the output I am getting when I try to run `vagrant plugin install` (clearly no plugin command in output):

```
Usage: vagrant [-v] [-h] command [<args>]

    -v, --version                    Print the version and exit.
    -h, --help                       Print this help.

 Available subcommands:
     box
     destroy
     gem
     halt
     init
     package
     provision
     reload
     resume
     ssh
     ssh-config
     status
     suspend
     up
```

I have tried installing vagrant from both apt and Rubygems and in both cases I get no plugin command. I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Which version do you actually have installed? I have 1.1.0 (on Win7), there is a `plugin` command.

Comment: Looks like you have an old version of vagrant for sure... try running `vagrant --version`, you will need vagrant 1.1+ for that command I think.

Comment: The version I have installed is 1.0.7 and like I said, was installed via gem.  If I install from apt I get the same thing.  I would install using a deb package but I cannot find one that will run since my machine is i386.  Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Vagrant from source.

The github repo is here: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant

And these instructions should allow you to build and install the bleeding edge version: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/wiki/Installing-Vagrant-from-source

If you want the latest stable version then once you have cloned the repo as described in the link above you should checkout the 1.2.2 tag with `git checkout v1.2.2` and then build that.

Comment: Finally got around to picking back up on this project, many thanks!